# Google Cloud Bitnami Magento 2.0.6 stack

Tags: php, google-app-engine, magento, magento2, bitnami

```
Magento 2.0.6
Bitnami stack
Google compute Instance.
```

So after going up and down through all support for **Bitnami Magento stack** on the web, I decided I am the only one with this issue.

So I had my site running flawlessly with the **Stack 2.0.6** given by **Bitnami** through the Cloud Launcher then I added an extension to setup the outgoing emails. And now I am unable to access my website using the domain name. If I enter my Domain name on any browser or computer it takes me to **"Apache2 Debian Default Page"** if I add **/index.php** to my Domain name it takes me to a **semi loaded version** of my **Magento store**. If I attempt to go to **domain/admin** it tells me, basically a **503 error**.

> There has been an error processing your request

So then I went through all my folders on the cloud and tried finding that `index.html` it loads with just the domain name and deleting them. After finding and deleting them it still loads the "`Apache2 Debian Default Page`". Very frustrating.
 So I decided to take a break then come back and thought maybe somehow the conf files are telling it to only open `index.html` first. So I went through all the **configs** and nothing is directing it that way.. so it seems everything loads correctly in the cloud instance no errors on the back end starting or restarting **Bitnami script** just the front end is broken somehow **apache2** isn't reaching the **Magento folder** correctly.

Then I decided, well if all else fails I will start a **new Cloud instance** with the new **2.0.7 Magento Bitnami**. Wrong instantly upon setup it directs the domain straight to **"Apache2 Debian Default Page"** except if add /admin to the fresh instance loads the backend and only loads the front end if I manually add `/index.php` to the **domain name**.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

it has configuration in

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf/
```

make sure to make changes in that 
you can change **DirectoryIndex index.php** in htaccess.conf

after that you can restart the apache by

```
service bitnami restart apache
```

Comment: I opened /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf/htaccess.conf 
verfied that DirectoryIndex index.php was correct. still same results, now i some how can access my website if i https://DOMAIN.COM then when i click on a product is links me back to http://DOMAIN.COM/product. I am also able to http://domain.com/admin and login and everything seems to work. I am just unable to View my website using just the domain name and have it direct to magentos inde.php.
I deleted every index.html file off the entire server yet its still showing up.

Comment: try restarting bitnami using : service bitnami restart

Comment: I have restarted all the Bitnami services muliple times and using your [ sudo service bitnami restart] and i have even stopped and started the VM.
I have multiple Domains linked to the magento which shouldn't matter. I am able to do everything find using SSL but when some one gos to the site without it it looks that stupid "Apache2 Debian Default Page" ( I wanna Kill that page) so then i added the Force SSL and it dont work and i also tried changing base urls to https instead of http.

Comment: are you using bitnami magento ? 
or simple bitnami image , as bitnami for magento works very fine with index.php and even domains